# cassandra java client using openssl

Tags: java, cassandra, openssl

I am trying to connect to cassandra cluster via java datastax driver with openssl as per this doc https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/ssl/ with my client cert and key and the truststore as my cassandra cluster requires two way mutual cert authentication

Here is my code

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        // make sure you close this stream properly (not shown here for brevity)
        InputStream trustStore = new FileInputStream("MyTrustStore");
        ks.load(trustStore, "abcdef".toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);

        SslContextBuilder builder = SslContextBuilder
          .forClient()
          .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
          .trustManager(tmf)
          // only if you use client authentication
          .keyManager(new File("client_cert"), new File("private_key"));


        SSLOptions sslOptions = new NettySSLOptions(builder.build());


        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
          .addContactPoint("w.x.y.z")
          .withSSL(sslOptions)
          .build();


    }
```

with the following dependencies in my pom

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
            <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I get an error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.ensureAvailability(OpenSsl.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:193)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:182)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslContext.<init>(OpenSslContext.java:34)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslClientContext.<init>(OpenSslClientContext.java:188)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:775)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:446)
    at com.example.App.main(App.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_osx_x86_64, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:421)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:89)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried removing the boringssl-static dep or the tcnative dep from pom but it still doesnt seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/331

Comment: @Jayr Thanks for your reply. I am using the latest version and also have added netty-tcnative in my dep. Not sure what else I can do based on the github issue.

Comment: Have you enabled trace? In the thread that was shared, there could be a message eventually about successfully loading the native after the class has created the 'so' in temp folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what could possibly be happening here is caused by some incompatibility between the versions of `netty`, `netty-tcnative` and `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` being used here.

In previous experimentation, I have found that versions of `netty` and `netty-tcnative` are particularly important as there can be incompatibilities between the two.

datastax java driver 3.6.0 depends on netty 4.0.56.Final and lists netty-tcnative 2.0.7.Final as an optional dependency.  You can also [find in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/ssl/#netty) for java driver 3.6.0 that 2.0.7.Final is recommended:

> There are known runtime incompatibilities between newer versions of netty-tcnative and the version of netty that the driver uses. For best results, use version 2.0.7.Final.

I also suspect that not using the same version of `netty-tcnative` and `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` might cause incompatibilities.  I would recommend trying the same versions.

Since I've tested this, I would first try the following configuration:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.Final</version>
        <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Created https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2267 to consider upgrading the java driver's netty 4.0.x dependency so newer versions of netty-tcnative will work with it.